# Accessing data from a grouped column

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that is using grouped columns to make the information easier to find.  Below is a sample of my data.[The screenshot below is the basic layout of the report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTAnb.png)  My issue is that to compute the percentage I need to pull Choice ID 6 for question 7 and Choice ID 2 for question 8.  I can get the total but, I cannot figure out how to define the Totals for the "Poor" and "No" responses that I need for the formula.

In the screen shot, the Choice_ID row is not needed and should be ignored.  That was an attempt to find a work around.  Either way there are 4 answer columns for question 7 and 2 answer columns for question 8.

Year    Choice ID   question_id Answer      Totals
2013    3                 7     Excellent   200
2013    3                 7     Excellent   122
2013    4                 7     Good         63
2013    4                 7     Good        115
2013    4                 7     Good        184
2013    4                 7     Good         19
2013    4                 7     Good        171
2013    5                 7     Satisf      127
2013    5                 7     Satisf      120
2013    5                 7     Satisf      129
2013    6                 7     Poor        136
2013    6                 7     Poor        181
2013    6                 7     Poor        172
2013    1                 8     Yes         114
2013    1                 8     Yes         104
2013    1                 8     Yes         157
2013    2                 8     No          171
2013    2                 8     No           11
2013    2                 8     No          164
2013    2                 8     No           96

Comment: Sorry, the example came out mushed up.

Answer (score 0):

Question_id needs to be removed from the column group and adding into the row group. The calculations you have set up for Totals and Percentages will work.

Comment: @phillip thanks for response.  I agree that that would work, but I want it in the column to keep each element in its own row.  I think that I have solved the issue by adding a column to the data in sql.  It seems to be working at the moment.